# Is possible to force implementation of an interface on a subclass where the parent already has an implementation?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract

I'm looking to force an implementation of an interface so that when any sub-classes of my parent class are created, I can guarantee the interface is implemented. As it inherits the implementation from the parent class, I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is a simplified view of my code....

```
public interface IPage {
    bool EvaluateLoadStatus();
    string PageTitle { get; }
}

public abstract class BasePage<T> {

}

public class HomePage : BasePage<HomePage>, IPage {

    [FindsBy("a[class*='close-all-tabs']", How.CssSelector)]
    public Control CloseAllTabsBtn;

    [FindsBy("//div[@role='tabpanel'][@class='tab-pane active']//div[@class='alerts']/div[contains(@class,'alert-success')]", How.XPath)]
    public Control RecordSavedSuccess;

    public string PageTitle { get; }

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) {
        PageFactory.InitializeElements<HomePage>(driver, this);
    }

    public void LogOut() {
        Click(inControl: ProfilePhoto).Click(inControl: LogOutLink);
    }

    public bool EvaluateLoadStatus() {
        //Implementation
    }        
}

public class UserPage : HomePage, IPage {
    //Is it possible to force an implementation of IPage here?
}
```

- I need to ensure that the developer is prompted to implement the interface when creating new sub-classes of HomePage.
- In my program I will need to be able to instantiate HomePage and sub-classes of HomePage such as UserPage.
- I need to be able to use implementations of both the `EvaluateLoadStatus()` method and the `PageTitle` property on instances of HomePage and instances of any sub-classes of HomePage
- **EDIT**: I also need access to certain properties, fields and methods on `HomePage` in any sub-classes

I'm open to design changes assuming it still allows for the points mentioned above.

**EDIT**: I've added some more code above to the `HomePage` class to demonstrate the issue. The Control's are initialized in the constructor and will be used both on instance of `HomePage` and any sub-classes.

Many thanks

Comment: No, you cannot enforce this with the requirements you have. You would have to supply a code analyzer or similar that points out the requirement.

Comment: What happens if your application calls `EvaluateLoadStatus` on a `HomePage` object?

Comment: I'd put all shared code into an `abstract HomePageBase` which marks the interface methods as `abstract` and have `HomePage` and `UserPage` inherit from this `abstract` base class.

Comment: That `NotImplementedException` points what something is wrong. You want `abstract EvaluateLoadStatus()` instead of throwing exception, means you must have base `abstract class` somewhere. Consider to implement `IPage` (as `abstract` members) either by `BasePage<T>` or by making another base `abstract class BasePageHomePage: BasePage<HomePage>, IPage` from which all pages are then inherited.

Comment: Make HomePage sealed, move all abstract parts to an abstract parent class which is the one others will have to descend from, forcing them to implement the abstract bits while still allowing you to instantiate HomePage. Those other descendants (of your abstract parent) won't be descendants of HomePage though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added some additional code and clarified a requirement that sub-classes of `HomePage` will need access to properties, fields and methods on `HomePage`, so having sub-classes inherit from an abstract class `HomePageBase` or similar won't work. I may need to rethink the design.

Comment: Why not? You can move all of the shared implementation into the abstract class and only leave the interface method as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your design seems "smelly" to me, but I don't see the whole construct.

If you really need the structure like you explained you can add another abstract class between `HomePage` and `UserPage`

```
public class HomePage : BasePage<HomePage>, IPage {

    public virtual bool EvaluateLoadStatus() { //MARK AS VIRTUAL
        //Implementation
    }        
}

public abstract class BaseUserPage : HomePage, IPage {

    public abstract override bool EvaluateLoadStatus();
}

public class UserPage : BaseUserPage , IPage {

    public abstract override bool EvaluateLoadStatus(){
        //new implementation
    }
}
```

But if the hierarchy need to stay as is. You cannot force the subclass to override your method at compile time.